# getting XML value very slow / time out C#

Tags: c#, xml

In my application i have to create a XML element, where i need to insert this value, after some checking (Which i why i have to convert it)

```
int currentXMLTimeValue = Convert.ToInt32(elemList[i].Attributes["tTime"].Value);
```

When debugging i get stuck at this line and can wait over 10 min and i get an time out exception. As you might have guess im running it through a loop, so it is very cruicial that i dont use that much time on the action.

my other convertion isn't slow at all

```
int currentEDFTimeValue = Convert.ToInt32(lines[j][2]);
```

It must then be the value call that uses time, how could i otherwise get this value or How can i speed this up?

```
elemList[i].Attributes["tTime"].Value
```

Here is the rest of the for loops

```
XmlWriter writer = null;
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(oldFile);
XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("test");

for (int j = 0; j < lines.Length; j++)
        {
            int currentEDFTimeValue = Convert.ToInt32(lines[j][2]); 
            for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
            {
                XmlElement newElem = doc.CreateElement(replacementElement);
                int currentXMLTimeValue = Int32.Parse(elemList[i].Attributes["tTime"].Value);
                if (currentEDFTimeValue != currentXMLTimeValue)
                {
                    newElem.SetAttribute("tTime", currentEDFTimeValue.ToString());

                    if (currentEDFTimeValue > currentXMLTimeValue)
                    {
                        eventNode.InsertAfter(newElem, elemList[i]);
                    }
                    else if (currentEDFTimeValue < currentXMLTimeValue)
                    {
                        eventNode.InsertBefore(newElem, elemList[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

These xml files might have more than 50,000 lines

**EDIT:**

Did some testing at found that this is very fast

```
 var test = elemList;
```

But getting the specific xml node is very slow

```
 var test = elemList[i];
```

Could it be because i add nodes/elements to the list while using it?

**EDIT2:**

I have another function that is more or less the same but this is also very fast

```
List<List<int>> offsets = new List<List<int>>();
 for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
            {
                var xmlDur = Convert.ToInt32(elemList[i].Attributes["duration"].Value);
                List<int> offset = new List<int>();
                for (int j = 0; j < lines.Length; j++)
                {
                            var edfDur = Convert.ToInt32(lines[j][4]);
                            if (Math.Abs(edfDur - xmlDur) <= 2)
                            {
                               for (int h = 0; h < offsets[offsets.Count - 2].Count; h++)
                               {
                                    startTimeDistance = Convert.ToInt32(elemList[i].Attributes["tTime"].Value) - Convert.ToInt32(lines[j][3]);
                                    offset.Add(startTimeDistance);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                if(offset.Count > 0) offsets.Add(offset);

            }
```

Comment: `Int32.Parse` is slightly faster, but what makes you think the `Convert` function is the bottleneck?

Comment: It's not `Convert.ToInt32` running slow. Edit your post with concise code that reproduces the problem, and we'll be able to help.

Comment: How many elements are you processing? How expensive is just the `elemList[i].Attributes["tTime"].Value` call?

Comment: I think the 'Attributes' collection is looking for all the child nodes for "tTime" attribute, that is probably causing it to run such a long time.

Comment: What's the environment? Is this a web application, Asp.net, or strictly PC-based? (10 minutes sounds like there must be some network communications involved.)

Comment: When I debug it gets stuck at this line and gets me a time out, ofcourse i could be getting elemList[i].Attributes["tTime"].Value
But my thinking was that as it only gets a value from a single xml node it would be fast. I will add more code for you liking.